# Why Associated table not updating properly using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest

I have created Employee and Department entities. These are having bidirectional many-to-one and one-to-many relation.

Using REST client, I add department and employees.

***Adding Department:***

```
{
  "name":"IT"
}
```

[image]

***Adding Employee:***

```
{"name": "Emp01" ,
 "address": 
    {
     "street" :"Street01" ,
     "city" :"City01" ,
     "state" :"State01" ,
     "country" :"Country01"
    },
 "department":{"id":"1"}
}
```

[image]

Now, I want to add a new department by associating an existing employee.

```
{
  "name":"Admin",
  "employees":
  [{
      "id":3
    }]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Now, department is added successfully but employee table is not updated properly. Except id other fields are blanked out. Ideally, hibernate should have updated employee with latest department id. Please let me know what could be missing here?
Thanks.

***Employee.java***

```
package com.empcatalogue.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Department department;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

***Department.java***

```
package com.empcatalogue.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

***EmployeeRepository.java***

```
...
...
...    
public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {


    Session session = RepoManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(emp);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

***DepartmentRepository.java***

```
...
...
...
    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        Session session = RepoManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(department);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can't add department by associating existing employee, if you want to associate an existing employee, you must do it later after you add a department.

Comment: First load your employee and then add to it the department, remember set employee in your department object.

Comment: My intention behind this question is to know, is there any way, wherein ORM tool will automatically update the associated entities without me loading them explicitly. In this case, without explicit loading of Employee while saving Department entity.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `javax.persistence` package for your implementation, but you tagged your question as being `Hibernate`. `Hibernate` is just one of the implementations of the JPA (Java Persistence API). Even the `Hibernate` Web page recommends to use JPA. Unless you're maintaining a legacy code, you better use JPA API to persist and fetch your entities.

Now to your question:

> Now, I want to add a new department by associating an existing employee.

To be able to persist as well as update your entities you should follow the following steps (code lines are just pseodo code):

- Create an instance of `Department` entity:

  ```
  Department dept = new Department();
  dept.setName(...);
  ```
- Fetch an existing `Employee` entity from the database within a transaction:

  ```
  Employee emp = session.get(Employee.class, <employee_id_here>);
  ```
- Wire the entity instances together:

  ```
  dept.getEmployees().add(emp);
  emp.setDepartment(dept);
  ```
- Persist the employee:

  ```
  session.save(dept);
  ```

You should do all these in a transaction and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @ujulu. It works by following the above procedure. This example is for a legacy system. As you mentioned, JPA is a better alternative in current time.